# Check Limits and requests for a pod with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

can anyone help me with the command to view limits and requests of a pod or containers in a pod? I have tried
`Kubectl describe pod` ,
`kubectl get pod --output=yaml` ,
`kubectl describe node` -  shows the current limits but not the configured limits. I want to see the configured limits and requests in the yaml.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "Configured limits" ? are you interested in used resources by the pod ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-Try following command :

```
kubectl get pods <podname> -o jsonpath='{range .spec.containers[*]}{"Container Name: "}{.name}{"\n"}{"Requests:"}{.resources.requests}{"\n"}{"Limits:"}{.resources.limits}{"\n"}{end}'
```

```
Example:
kubectl get pods frontend -o jsonpath='{range .spec.containers[*]}{"Container Name: "}{.name}{"\n"}{"Requests:"}{.resources.requests}{"\n"}{"Limits:"}{.resources.limits}{"\n"}{end}'
Container Name: app
Requests:{"cpu":"250m","memory":"64Mi"}
Limits:{"cpu":"500m","memory":"128Mi"}
Container Name: log-aggregator
Requests:{"cpu":"250m","memory":"64Mi"}
Limits:{"cpu":"500m","memory":"128Mi"}
```